# Bootstrap dropdown menus only working on homepage (Joomla 3.0)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu, joomla3.0

I have a strange thing happening with my custom Joomla 3.0 template that uses Bootstrap dropdown menus. It works perfectly well on my localhost and on the homepage of my remote host site. However, when I click on any of the links the dropdown feature ceases to work and all the submenu items become visible an unsightly lists!

I've inspected the generated code and it seems as though my javascript is only processed correctly on the homepage but seems to be completely ignored everywhere else. I have included the following code at the bottom of my index.php document to insert the classes as it's a Joomla site and not hand coded (THAT I could cope with!!):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // dropdown
      $('.parent').addClass('dropdown');
      $('.parent > a').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
      $('.parent > a').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
      $('.parent > a').append(' ', '<span class="caret"></span>');
      $('.parent > ul').addClass('dropdown-menu');
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

The top level menu items are being triggered by external links pointing to the # character and, as I said, the script is being implemented on the localhost and, bizarrely, on the remotely hosted homepage but not on any other page which makes no sense to me at all.

I hope someone has some ideas as to what might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure top menu module's sub-menu to always display.

From Joomla 3 back end, go to module manager

Find the menu for which you want the sub-menu drop down

In this menu module configuration, go to options tab

Configure "Show Sub-menu items" setting to yes

Save changes

I suggest you check the sub-menu displays in all of the pages you want this sub-menu to appear before you enable the sub menu drop code. Then, add the javascript code to implement the bootstrap drop down effect.

[image: go to module manager]

[image: from module configuration, go to options tab]

[image: set show sub-menu items setting to yes]

Answer (score 1):

Ok for starters don't set top level links to be external URLS, set them as you would normally.  If you use external URLS, it breaks SITEMAPs etc and any breadcrumb stylings wont work correctly.  Instead update your javascript to remove the href's and replace them with "#". I have attached the javascript below it does a bit more than yours

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // dropdown

        jQuery('.parent').addClass('dropdown');
        jQuery('.parent > a').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
        jQuery('.parent > a').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
        jQuery('.nav > .parent > a').attr('href','#');
        jQuery('.parent > a').append('<span class="caret"></span>');
        jQuery('.parent > ul').addClass('dropdown-menu');
        jQuery('.nav-child .parent').removeClass('dropdown');
        jQuery('.nav-child .parent').addClass('dropdown-submenu');
        jQuery('.dropdown-submenu > a').removeAttr('class');
        jQuery('.dropdown-submenu > a').removeAttr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
        jQuery('.dropdown-submenu > a > span').remove();
    });
```

This should effectively fix your menus, as mentioned above you also need to ensure all submenus are rendered at page load, ie they are visible.

Additionally you might want to consider moving your javascript into a seperate js file located in /template/$yourtemplate/js  and then calling it as a load from the index.php template file like

```
$doc->addScript('templates/' . $this->template . '/js/template.js', 'text/javascript');
```

this is another call to the server so it does increase the server strain slightly, but it keeps all your extra "bits" of js in one place (and in the header where they should be)

This answer is based on using Joomla 3.2 with bootstrap 2.3.1 and Jquery 1.9.1 (both default with this version of Joomla)